# How to: aria-label of button inside ngFor referencing ngFor elements?

Tags: html, angular, accessibility

I have a ngFor div that includes a span and a button and I need the aria-label to reference the element name for accessibility reasons

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <span>{{element.elementName}}</span>
  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="'Remove ' + {{element.elementName}} + ' from elements'"
          (click)="removeElement(element)">
    <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
interface ElementModel {
  elementID: number,
  elementName: string,
}

elements: ElementModel[] = [
  {elementID: 0, elementName:'Name1'},
  {elementID: 1, elementName:'Name2'}
];
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error message:

```
Can't bind to 'aria-label' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

How can I reference the element from the ngFor inside the aria-label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[attr.]` for [binding attributes](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding):

```html
<button [attr.aria-label]="'Remove ' + element.elementName + ' from elements'">
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Was confused because a normal aria-label worked if I didn't include element